# Magento 2 Get Media Gallery in productlist

Tags: magento2, product-images, media, gallery

In Magento 1 I've always used

```
$_product->getMediaGallery('images')
```

But in the source from Magento 2 I see

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
echo $productImage->toHtml();
```

It's only getting the first product image. How do I get the second or third image (not only the base one)?

GetMediaGallery function doesn't exists?

$_product->getMediaGalleryImages() throws NULL in a var_dump

and

for getMediaGallery and getMediaGalleryEntries I get the same notice error:

```
Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::$getMediaGallery
```

Answer (score 7):

create helper for example :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ibnab\Common\Helper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler as GalleryReadHandler;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
  protected $galleryReadHandler;
    /**
     * Catalog Image Helper
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $imageHelper;
    public function __construct(
    GalleryReadHandler $galleryReadHandler,  \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper)
    {
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->galleryReadHandler = $galleryReadHandler;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
   /** Add image gallery to $product */
    public function addGallery($product) {
        $this->galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
    }
    public function getGalleryImages(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                /** @var $image \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image */
                $image->setData(
                    'small_image_url',
                    $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'medium_image_url',
                    $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
                        ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'large_image_url',
                    $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
                        ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
            }
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

call and use inside your list.phtml :
**$_helperGallery = $this->helper('Ibnab\Common\Helper\Data');**
now you can use with current called product inside for each (with you technique):

```
  <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <ul class="product-item-wrapper">
                                <?php
                                $_helperGallery->addGallery($_product);
                                $images = $_helperGallery->getGalleryImages($_product);
                                if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
                                    $i = 1;
                                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                                        $item = $image->getData();
                                        if (isset($item['media_type']) && $item['media_type'] == 'image'):
                                            ?>
                                            <?php if ($i == 1): ?>
                                                <li class="selected">
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                <li >
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo isset($item['medium_image_url']) ? $item['medium_image_url'] : null; ?>" alt="Preview image">
                                            </li>
                                            <?php
                                            $i++;
                                        endif;
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </a>
```

the complete [source of course](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/call-media-gallery-product-images-in-product-list)