# How can I get the second Image of a product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I want to use the first and the second image of a product, I'm now able to use the first one. But how can I reach the second image?

Does the `$_product->getMediaGallery('images')` exists in Magento 2?
If not how can I reach the same goal?

I tried to use this:

```
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $product_img) :
    echo $product_img;
endforeach;
```

And i recived the following error "Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/XXX/xxx/Magento_T‌​heme/templates/xxxx.‌​phtml on line 27"

Comment: You can use `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages();` to get media images in Magento 2

Comment: Please add your code to your question to check the error.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya there it is

Comment: Please add line where you are instantiating `$product` in your code. Are you loading it using Product factory?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya , I just create a block for that and I get each product from $block->getProductCollection()

Comment: Please refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124779/2443

Answer (score 0):

There is a [getMediaGalleryImages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1464-L1485) function in the Magento\Catalog\Model\Product class which will return the media gallery images.